# Filtering in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, filtering, apache-poi

I just started using the Apache POI to work on data from and Excel spreadsheet in Java. Right now I'm just tinking around. However, I can't seem to understand how the setAutoFilter function works. Could someone please explain it or give a link to some piece of code that shows Excel data being filtered.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:N1"));
```